# bad interpreter: No such file or directory when running pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Whenever I try to run pip (with or without any of the options) I get something like this:

```
$ pip --version
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.16/pyenv.d/exec/pip-rehash/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip: /usr/local/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Running `which pip` however, returns me `/Users/jalee/.pyenv/shims/pip` which is an expected behaviour.

Not sure why this is happening

> python3 -c "print('working')"

print `working` just fine

Comment: Seems like python3 is broken, try `python3 -c "print('working')"` - and if it fails try to reinstall python3

Comment: Advice (not an answer): Never use the `pip somecommand` scripts, instead use the _pip_ executable modules with the targeted Python interpreter explicitly: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @Skarlett `python3 -c "print('working')"` prints `working` just fine.

Comment: Try full path: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: for me commands with pip3 are working.. e.g - pip3 --version

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `pip` instead of `pip3`.

> "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

seems to mean that a wrong (not bad) interpreter is being used to interpret a Python file.

In my case, it seems that I was trying to install a Python 2 program with a Python 3 installer. In your case, it looks like you are trying to use a Python 2 version of pip, which processes Python 2 files, to install a Python 3 file.

Your submission indicates that your pip (which may be intended for Python 2) is associated with a Python 3 interpreter. Perhaps you might try uninstalling pip then reinstall it making sure that you get the Python 3 version.

I am currently using miniconda 3 which provides both `pip` and `pip3`.